# Youtube Data API on Java

Tags: java, android, youtube

I have a youtube video id ""a81259a0-a2f5-464b-866e-71220f2739f1" and I must get link for this id similar "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zc5AnJnyrY". How can I do that?

Comment: Where did this video id come from?  As you noted it doesn't look like a typical YT id.

Answer (score 0):

YT is generating videoIDs on their own... and to get id of video you have to parse user uploads xml like http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/yrf/uploads and under  tag you can have video id